# Notepad ++ separate all entries by space

Tags: regex, notepad++

Following is my text file, columns are separated by single, double or multiple spaces or even tab separated. I'm not sure of the formatting. How to separate all columns only by a single space.Thanks.

sample.txt

```
Name       Roll        Read
id\asd4r  101_Saoi_09   poll
id\plo90d   CPS_TR5     ET_dev
id\rbh906   coer_web    AA_ITECTS
id\o9i8u7   000125_Telease  check-2
......
......
```

I tried constructing regex but cant get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+`
- Replace with:      a space
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+     : 1 or more horizontal spaces (space or tabulation)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Name Roll Read
id\asd4r 101_Saoi_09 poll
id\plo90d CPS_TR5 ET_dev
id\rbh906 coer_web AA_ITECTS
id\o9i8u7 000125_Telease check-2
```

Comment: Good answer, wasn't aware of `\h`. So `\h` essentially means `[ \t]` (space or tab), right?

Comment: @degant: Yes it does. It also includes unicode spaces. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: @Toto : Well constructed answer. +1 for \h

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to just replace all occurrences of one or more spaces with just a single space.  Try the following find and replacement in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
[ ]+
```

**Replace:**

```
[ ]
```

Comment: Won't `\s` also match line delimiters (`\n`, `\r` etc.)?

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your time and the alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Find  `+` (space followed by +) and replace with  (single space)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xUMCOO/1/)

**Note:** that the above regex only match spaces (and not tabs). For the regex to work for tabs too, you could use `[ \t]+` (space or tab) while searching.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.